# Require double quote for array values in Rails like ["1","2","3"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid3

I am working with form_tags in rails and using MongoDB for my application.

Using the form_tag i am getting params[:ids] using post method like this

```
["5262353ebd521b131a000010", "526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002"]
```

And i am saving this params[:id] as hidden_field as

```
<%= f.hidden_field :ids, :value => params[:ids].join(","), :multiple => true %>
```

But its storing in the MongoDB like this

```
"ids" : [
        "5262353ebd521b131a000010,526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002"
    ],
```

But instead of this i need to store as,

```
"ids" : [
        "5262353ebd521b131a000010","526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002"
    ],
```

with **double quote**,
For single id its working fine. For multiple values its not storing as above.

Please help me in this regard.

Comment: Before you save the object, split the string in `params[:ids]` to make it an array.

Comment: but it will display as "[[\"5262353ebd521b131a000010\", \"526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002\"]]". So for make it MangoDB ObjectID i need to store as ["1","2","3"].

Comment: Well, fix your display code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hidden field for each value so that when posting to your controller you get it as an array:

```
<% params[:ids].each do |id| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag "ids[]", id %>
<% end %>
```

With that, you'll get an array in your action and you can directly store params[:ids] with your model.

Answer (score 1):

try for this `<%= f.hidden_field :ids, :value => params[:ids].join('","'), :multiple => true %>`

Comment: if you are having error in parsing `"` (double quotes),escape them and try again.

Comment: Yes, already tried but it results like this, "doctor_ids" : [
  "5262353ebd521b131a000010\",\"526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002"
 ],

Answer (score 0):

```
<% params[:ids].each do |id| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :ids, :value => id, :multiple => :true %>
<% end %>
```

This works and my MongoDB is,

```
   "ids" : [
        ObjectId("526b47f8bd521bd1b3000002"),
        ObjectId("5262353ebd521b131a000010")
    ],

Cheers!!!
```